# two different ping results to the same machine, what does this mean?

Tags: networking, ping

I am trying to track down a network or possibly server issue, and I opened a ping to the server from my machine.

I will generally receive a <1ms response for a period of time, say 10+ minutes.   Then, I will see a jump to 10ms, and it will climb to 20, 30, even 60ms (up and down during this time) for seconds to up to several minutes.

During one of these events, I opened a second dos window on the same machine and pinged to the same server (windows).    While the original window was bouncing between 20 and 60ms, the new ping window was showing a solid <1ms!!!

Any thoughts on what this means?

I am thinking I might have a network loop somewhere out there, and the ping occasionally finds it?

Comment: What exactly is between your machine and the server? Multiple switches? Any routing? Load balancing?

Comment: `1.` If there were a network loop the symptoms would be consistent, extreme and constant. `2.` Ping isn't a network performance analysis tool.